# How to configure TLS when using SSL in Angular 6?

Tags: angular, ssl, angular-cli

in AngularJS v1.6, I was able to control exactly what TLS version to use with the SSL setup I made in my Node.js server, using a structure like this:

```
var options = { ..., ca: some-ca-file, cert: some-cert-file, key: some-key-file, **secureProtocol: 'TLSv1_2_method'**, requestCert: true, rejectUnauthorized: true, ... };
```

and then passed that structure to the https.createServer() method.  But, how do I setup TLS in the "ng serve" command using the Angular CLI?  While running the 'Tour of Heroes' tutorial from the online Angular documentation, I notice that the server automatically includes TLSv1.0, 1.1, & 1.2, as what I saw using a TLS scanning tool.  Specifically, I need to eliminate the use of TLSv1.0.

Comment: The CLI serve command is only intended for local development, in production you'll probably be serving compiled static files from something else.

Comment: Thanks jonrsharpe!  Is there a proper way to generate those pre-compiled static files?  Can you suggest a nice Angular book or website I can refer to to learn that technique?  I already know how to setup a Node.js server, so I'm half-way there.

Comment: [`ng build`](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build)? And note that recommendations for off site resources are off topic here.

Comment: Ah, I see.  Okay, I think I can take it from there.  Again, I greatly appreciate you help!